# C# circular dependcy of two class, interfaces obj unable to create?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 2 class projects. mqtt and Vm. so Vm class already referencing mqtt class and it works fine. now I want to creates a object of VM class in mqtt class project, which I understand create a circular dependency if I refer to the Vm class.
so I  understand from google that I have to use interface, so I did and below is my code as follows.

mqtt class:

```
public class MqttControllerClass
    {
        InterfaceClass Mcallback = new MqttControllerClass(); //error here**
        private  void Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {


             if (Mcallback != null)  // always null here **
                 Mcallback.call_queryEvent();
        }
   }
```

Vm class:

```
using MqttInterface;

namespace oadr2b_ven.ven
{
    public class VenWrapper : resources.ISendReport,MqttInterface.InterfaceClass
    {
 public void call_queryEvent()
        {
            queryEvents();
        }

    }
}
```

now the interface class:

```
namespace MqttInterface
{
    public interface InterfaceClass 
    {
        void call_queryEvent();

    }
}
```

so the issue is that if I don't declare in mqtt class a object the projects runs withour error but `Mcallback != null` is always null.

so I decide to create a interface object and I do this.

```
InterfaceClass Mcallback = new MqttControllerClass();
```

which throws me the below error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MqttBroker.MqttControllerClass' to 'MqttInterface.InterfaceClass'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?
```

I ask you guys I am new to c#. what am I dong wrong ? is there a better method ?
let me know. thanks.

Comment: @Anil Gadiyar, there is a big confusion in your description. You create an interface, apply it to class VenWrapper and you want to use it with and instance of MqttControllerClass? Where does the VenWrapper intereacts with MqttControllerClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. all you have to do is assign the object of interfaced class using a callback method to the mqtt class.

```
namespace MqttInterface
{
    public interface InterfaceClass 
    {
        void call_queryEvent();

    }
 public void setCallbackHandler(InterfaceClass callbackHandler)
        {
               Mcallback = callbackHandler;
          }// obj is assigned from Vm class
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Your class definition is not implementing the needed interface:

```
public class MqttControllerClass
{
    InterfaceClass Mcallback = new MqttControllerClass(); //error here**
}
```

You should be using:

```
public class MqttControllerClass : InterfaceClass 
{
    InterfaceClass Mcallback = new MqttControllerClass(); //error here**
}
```

Because if `MqttControllerClass`does not implement `InterfaceClass`, then you can't assign an object of type `MqttControllerClass` to a variable of type `InterfaceClass`.

**This only solves the error you mentioned, but you're still dealing with badly designed code.** Read on for further information.

---

I am wondering why you are taking this approach.

When you create an `MqttControllerClass` object, its `Mcallback` gets populated with **another new** `MqttControllerClass` object. **Why???**

First of all, this will create an infinite loop (every newly instantiated `MqttControllerClass`will cause another new `MqttControllerClass` to be instantiated, thus creating an endless loop).

Disregarding the infinite loop, I don't even understand the justification for wanting to do this. It can make sense to have a class with the property of the same type, e.g. :

```
public class Person
{
    public Person father;
    public Person mother;
}
```

But it makes no sense to fill these properties with newly instantiated `Person` objects every time you instantiate a `Person` object.

Comment: This is not very helpful, this code is always going to crash with this site's name.

Comment: @HansPassant: I was already elaborating on that point when you typed your comment, see the update :)

Comment: Hi guys,  get the point. whats the possible solution here ? :)

Comment: @AnilGadiyar: That depends, what are you trying to achieve? Why do you think the `Mcallback` property needs to have a default value? Why do you think it needs to have a **new** object instantiated, as opposed to referring to an existing object?

Comment: @Flater what I am trying to achieve is mqtt class must call a method in Vm class, to do that I need to reference the Vm class in mqtt project correct ?     but since Vm class is already reference mqtt class. It create a circular dependenies. now I just wanna know a better way to implement without any circular issue:) ?

Comment: @AnilGadiyar: Based on your comment, you should be doing `InterfaceClass Mcallback = new VenWrapper(); ` (which is consistent with how your interfaces were initially set up), as opposed to `InterfaceClass Mcallback = new MqttControllerClass();` (which is recursive and inherently impossible to achieve inside the `MqttControllerClass` class)

Comment: I cannot call VenWrapper  in mqtt class as it creates circular dependy

Comment: @AnilGadiyar: Then your question is not complete. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, nor is there any explanation why your classes are separated over several projects. You'd need to reevaluate the structural composition of your solution, which is out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155893/discussion-between-anil-gadiyar-and-flater).

Comment: @AnilGadiyar: My answer is an answer to the question that was posted here. Any further problems should be addressed in a new question (if it is indeed valid to post it on SO, of course)